# Produce PHP function Call for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, backtracking

I'm using wordpress. I want to view like a backtrace for all the function that wordpress calls. Is this possible with php only or if not, where can i insert debug_backtrace() to view all the function call??

Answer (score 0):

`debug_backtrace()` (when dumped) will show you the function calls and includes leading to the function within which you call the trace. You can't ask it to do a stack for the whole application (unless the whole application is just one long series of function calls and includes, and in that case you'd still have to find the last step and put the trace call in there).

So for Wordpress, if you're trying to get a feel for the application by trial-and-error, you could try adding the trace in places where you think it is likely.